# Does link_to automatically pass :id when controller is specified?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a link_to code

```
<%= link_to "#{(pages_counter/2) + 1}", { controller: "videos", action: 'videos_navigate', offset: pages_counter }, remote: true %>
```

When clicking on the link it's passing the id of the video automatically meaning I didn't explicitly pass a video object or an id via the link_to code.  Is this happening because I directly identified the controller and the action as seen in the code above?  Thanks in advance

sample URL generated: /videos/videos_navigate/1?offset=2

Comment: Can you show the url it generated for you?

Comment: Are you making pagination links?  Any reason you aren't using Will Paginate?

Comment: @fatfrog I was unfamiliar with will paginate until you mentioned it, yes i am making pagination links.  I'll look into the gem would still be nice to know why the :id is being passed however.

Comment: @BenLee forgot to mention your name in my reply

Comment: Yeah, I saw your update. I don't know the answer either, would like to know too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are on a show page, where the ID is in the URL already, and your link_to doesn't specify an ID, it will pick up the ID from the URL .  The same thing would happen if you did not specify the controller, it would instead grab the current controller you are in.

So if you went to record 2 and click the same link, your URL will be /videos/videos_navigate/2?offset=2

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you link directly to the route instead.  As in, run `rake routes` int he console, it should print out an path name for your `videos_navigate` path... then you can presumably link to it like this:

```
<%= link_to "#{(pages_counter/2) + 1}", videos_navigate_path, :remote => true %>
```

If it doesn't already have a path, then you can give it one by adding `:as => 'videos_navigate'` to your route declaration for the action inside your `config.routes.rb` file.  [Read here for more information on routing and paths](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html).

Comment: I'm matching the route and it doesn't give me a path name: match 'concerts/videos_navigate/:id' => 'concerts#videos_navigate'

Comment: Ok will do!  Thanks, is that the preferred method of most rails devs?

Comment: Yessir.  You should be able to just change it to `match 'concerts/videos_navigate/:id' => 'concerts#videos_navigate', :as => 'videos_navigate'` and then when you run `rake routes` it should give you a path name.  That being said if you have `/:id` on your route like that, then it's expecting a parameter at the end.  So you would probably need to end up linking to `videos_navigate_path(1)` or some other id number.

Comment: Why is that best practice?  To me it seems like you're making more work for yourself.

Comment: Because once you have the path setup you never have to change it, and you can use the `redirect_to` command, or have forms point to the path.  Also it's just cleaner/shorter than having to spell out the full URL every time.  I think the most powerful part of routing is to use the [resources](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resource-routing-the-rails-default).  It generates a bunch of paths for you and keeps your logic consistent from Controller to Controller in terms of how classes are created/viewed/edited/destroyed/etc.